# Google-Colab tutorial on Tensorflow-federated failing when launching Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorboard, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to run the Google Colab [found here](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification), which is a tutorial for `tensorflow-federated`. First of all, there is an error in the Colab section **Displaying model metrics on Tensorboard**, in the cell:

```
#@test {"skip": true}
with summary_writer.as_default():
  for round_num in range(1, NUM_ROUNDS):
    state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
    for name, value in metrics.train._asdict().items():
      tf.summary.scalar(name, value, step=round_num)
```

which gets solved in the following way:

```
#@test {"skip": true}
with summary_writer.as_default():
  for round_num in range(1, NUM_ROUNDS):
    state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
    for name, value in metrics['train'].items():
      tf.summary.scalar(name, value, step=round_num)
```

However I am stuck in the same section because, when trying to run tensorboard I get the error:

```
ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1).
Contents of stderr:
2020-10-15 07:50:26.425571: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64-nvidia
2020-10-15 07:50:26.425634: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 75, in run_main
    app.run(tensorboard.main, flags_parser=tensorboard.configure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 289, in main
    return runner(self.flags) or 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 305, in _run_serve_subcommand
    server = self._make_server()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 419, in _make_server
    ingester.deprecated_multiplexer,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 149, in TensorBoardWSGIApp
    experimental_middlewares,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 257, in __init__
    "Duplicate plugins for name %s" % plugin.plugin_name
ValueError: Duplicate plugins for name projector
```

Searching for the error, as other posts suggested, I tried to uninstall/reinstall the packages `tf-nightly` and `tensorflow`, but it did not solve. Assuming the problem is generated by package conflicts, the versions of the most relevant Colab packages are the following:

```
tb-nightly                    2.4.0a20201014          
tblib                         1.7.0                   
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.7.0                   
tensorboardcolab              0.0.22                  
tensorflow                    2.3.0                   
tensorflow-addons             0.8.3                   
tensorflow-datasets           2.1.0                   
tensorflow-estimator          2.3.0                   
tensorflow-federated-nightly  0.16.1.dev20201014      
tensorflow-gcs-config         2.3.0                   
tensorflow-hub                0.9.0                   
tensorflow-metadata           0.24.0                  
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.4.1                   
tensorflow-privacy            0.5.1                   
tensorflow-probability        0.11.0                  
termcolor                     1.1.0                   
terminado                     0.9.1                   
testpath                      0.4.4                   
text-unidecode                1.3                     
textblob                      0.15.3                  
textgenrnn                    1.4.1                   
tf-estimator-nightly          2.4.0.dev2020101401     
tf-nightly                    2.4.0.dev20201014       
tfa-nightly                   0.12.0.dev20201012231340
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/914 and was likely fixed in https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/commit/2add5c8d9dbb5945f6f8240b13965292625a8f65.

This should be in TFF `0.17.0` and later.